# Insert or Update in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

my table is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BrowseHistory (
id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
tid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
data BLOB NOT NULL)
```

what I want to do is give tid and data, I want to find if there's not a record's tid == given tid, then insert it( the id is the max(id) + 1). If there is, check if the id is equal to max(id) ,if not set the id to max(id) +1.
I used the following sql, it can work ,but it will always set the id equals to max(id) + 1

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO BrowseHistory (id, tid, data) values ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0) FROM BrowseHistory) + 1, ?, ?)
```

Comment: The replace function works based on conflict resolution between primary keys. Since your `tid` is not the primary key of the table this idea is not going to work.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Actually, `tid` *is* the primary key of that table.

Comment: The SQL as given will always try to work out which id is the max, then add 1, and use that. If I understand correctly you want to inspect the row being updated in case of conflict, and decide then whether to update the id. This is not possible with `insert or replace`. `insert or replace` will first work out which values to try to insert, and if that fails due to a primary key conflict, will update the corresponding rows, but you cannot write conditional expressions in the `VALUES` clause that work with the knowledge of whether this became an insert or an update.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I totally missed the create table statement there. Having an id field in the table that is not the primary key is a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in SQLite itself.

Do this from your actual programming language:

```py
cursor.execute("UPDATE ...")
if cursor.rowcount == 0:
    cursor.execute("INSERT ...")
```

Comment: Ok. I wonder if there's a one line sqlite sentence can solve it.

Comment: I will not remove the first sentence of my answer just because you don't like it. :-)